# Support of several iOS - application development

Tags: ios, deployment, ios6

With the release of iOS6, I am going to update my application using the new feature of iOS6, such as UICollectionView.

When I will deploy it on App Store, my application will be only available for devices on iOS6.

Question: How can I let the devices on iOS 5.1 using the older release which do not use UICollectionView?

I could go more deeper by asking: What is the strategy to upgrade an application without loosing the users which have not yet upgrade their OS?

Thank you for your advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one will work perfectly:

```
NSString * systemVersion = [[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion];
if ([self.systemVersion compare:@"5.0" options:NSNumericSearch] != NSOrderedAscending)
    {
    osHigherThaniOS5 = TRUE;
    }

if ([self.systemVersion compare:@"6.0" options:NSNumericSearch] != NSOrderedAscending)
    {
    osHigherThaniOS6 = TRUE;
    }
```

Just determine the system version and set your conditions accordingly  :)

Answer (score 2):

You could check for availability of new iOS6 classes with `Class tmp = NSClassFromString(@"UIActivityViewController");
    if (tmp) {//use iOS6 class}else{//do something else}`. Also, you could use some macros, like `__IPHONE_5_0`, put some code between `#ifndef` or `#if defined(...)`. Good Luck!

Comment: It means that an application build with the iOS6 sdk will work on an iOS 5 device if it does not use any iOS6 components?